# Querying elasticsearch -- get document count per node, per host

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Okay, so the architecture is that we have multiple nodes (between 3 and 5) running on each host connected to our ELK stack.

I am trying to write a query that is basically going to say how many documents appear on each host and each node.

Right now node is it's own field...

The way that I would query this in kibana would be something like

Host: "1-18" AND Node: 03

Would pull up that host... I'm trying to determine for each host, and each node on the host, how many documents exist in the last 24 hours, and the query isn't making a lot of sense.  When I try to use 2 fields, it's not working.  When I try to use 2 ranges that's not working either.

I use the following to get document counts for each host:

```
{"size": 0,"aggs" : {"langs" : {"terms" : { "field" : "host" }}}}
```

Is adding a per-node aggregation that difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add a sub-aggregation under your `host` one, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "hosts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "host"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nodes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "node"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Kibana, you can do this visually by going into the Visualize tab and picking a Pie Chart. Then use a `terms` aggregation on the `host` field and then click "+ Add sub-buckets" and use another `terms` aggregation on the `node` field.

[image]